# How to push null in specify array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

For example I have an associative array

```
08.02: (0) []
09.02: (1) [301]
10.02: (3) [null, null, null]
11.02: (3) [839, 695, 410]
12.02: (3) [null, null, null]
13.02: (3) [839, 679, 407]
14.02: (3) [null, null, null]
15.02: (3) [null, null, null]
16.02: (2) [403, null]
17.02: (3) [840, 690, 410]
```

So I want to push null in arrays , in which length is **not 3**.
For example before push in to Array I have :

```
09.02: (1) [301]
```

But after push I want to have:

```
09.02: (3) [301, null, null]
```

**EDIT: Thank you for help, I forgot about while loop.**

Comment: Do we need make all the arrays with same size. i.,e if there is one element also we need to make the array length to 3 by inserting nulls ?

Answer (score 1):

Just push until it's 3 long.

```js
var arr = [301];
while(arr.length<3){
    arr.push(null);
}
console.log(arr); // Array(3) [ 301, null, null ]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, here's one way

```js
const obj = {
    08.02: [],
    09.02: [301],
    10.02: [null, null, null],
    11.02: [839, 695, 410],
    12.02: [null, null, null],
    13.02: [839, 679, 407],
    14.02: [null, null, null],
    15.02: [null, null, null],
    16.02: [403, null],
    17.02: [840, 690, 410]
}

for (let key in obj) {
   while (obj[key].length < 3) {
     obj[key].push(null)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to have a function like this:

```js
const fillUpToN = <A>(as: A[], n: number = 3): A[] =>
  as.length < n ? as.concat(Array(n - as.length).fill(null)) : as;

const a = [1, 2]
const b = [1]
fillUpToN(a) // [1, 2, null]
fillUpToN(b) // [1, null, null]
```

This looks at the argument's length to determine whether we should concatenate anything at the end, and leaves it untouched if it's already long enough.

A default parameter can be used to generalise the function even more.

```js
fillUpToN(b, 5) // [1, null, null, null, null]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `JavaScript` **does not** have `associative arrays`. So perhaps what you're using is an `object`. If that's the case, then what you could do is the following:

```js
const obj = {
  "08.02": [],
  "09.02": [301],
  "10.02": [null, null, null],
  "11.02": [839, 695, 410],
  "12.02": [null, null, null],
  "13.02": [839, 679, 407],
  "14.02": [null, null, null],
  "15.02": [null, null, null],
  "16.02": [403, null],
  "17.02": [840, 690, 410]
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
  const arr = obj[key];
  if (arr.length === 3) {
    return { key, items: arr };
  }
  const nulls = Array.from({ length: 3 - arr.length }).map(() => null);

  return {
    key,
    items: [...arr, ...nulls]
  };
}).reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  return {
    ...accumulator,
    [item.key]: item.items
  }
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Alternatively, if you just have an `array` with `sub arrays` in it, you could do something like the following:

```js
const arr = [
  [],
  [301],
  [null, null, null],
  [839, 695, 410],
  [null, null, null],
  [839, 679, 407],
  [null, null, null],
  [null, null, null],
  [403, null],
  [840, 690, 410]
];

const result = arr.map(subArray => {
  if (subArray.length === 3) {
    return subArray;
  }
  const nulls = Array.from({ length: 3 - subArray.length }).map(() => null);

  return [...subArray, ...nulls];
});

console.log(result);
```